# Тг бот не выводит весь список

Tags: python, requests, telebot, beautiful-soup, список

Я написал тг бота, который парсит данные с сайта и пишет в лс.
Суть проблемы в том, что он выводит только одну новость, а я хочу чтобы он вывел все новости которые записаны в переменную news.
Я пытался разными способами решить проблему, но не один не помог(в комментариях некоторые строчки кода - попытки решения проблемы). Я пробовал через глобальную переменную, через цикл, но выводится лишь одна новость.
Хотя странно что тут выводится все новости:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_news():
    url = "https://ria.ru/world/"
    
    req = requests.get(url)
    src = req.text
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")

    news = soup.find_all(class_="list-item__title color-font-hover-only")#.find_all("title").text
    for item in news:
        print(item.text)


get_news()
```

А уже в главном коде выводится лишь одна новость

```
import telebot
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from telebot import types


def get_news():
    url = "https://ria.ru/world/"
        
    #headers = {
    #    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"
    #    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
    #}
        
    req = requests.get(url)#headers = headers
    src = req.text
    #print(src)
    #with open("index.html", "w") as file:
        #file.write(src)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
    #global news
    news = soup.find_all(class_="list-item__title color-font-hover-only")#.find_all("title").text
    #print(news)
    for item in news:
        print(item.text)
        return item.text
bot = telebot.TeleBot('5773397252:AAFeuY70n9B_Rxej7qr7pdeOwmkfgcXadZ4')
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text == "Новости мира":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,get_news())#get_news()
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

UPD: я переписал чуть-чуть и теперь этот кусок кода выглядит вот так

```
for item in news:
    items = item.txt
return items
```

Но это всё равно не помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто заранее объяви переменную, а после её редактуры возвращай

```
def get_news():
    ...
    
    result = ""
    for item in news:
        result += f"{item.text}\n"
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

`return item.text` является лишней строчкой.
Ваша функция `get_news()` прекращает свою работу после возвращения элемента цикла, поскольку `return` останавливает работу функции, и является чем-то похожими на `break`, стоит просто его убрать, и все будет работать нормально

Теперь код вашей функции должен выглядеть так:

```py
def get_news():
    url = "https://ria.ru/world/"
        
    #headers = {
    #    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"
    #    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
    #}
        
    req = requests.get(url)#headers = headers
    src = req.text
    #print(src)
    #with open("index.html", "w") as file:
        #file.write(src)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
    #global news
    news = soup.find_all(class_="list-item__title color-font-hover-only")#.find_all("title").text
    #print(news)
    for item in news:
        print(item.text)
```

Comment: Если так делать, то функция нечего не возвращает, следовательно бот нечего не пишет, а так инфа полезная

Comment: Извиняюсь, не заметил. Тогда стоит просто выделить переменную под цикл или использовать сразу команду бота на отправку сообщений